# Using Clang thread-safety analysis with C11 and __attribute__((cleanup))

Tags: c, thread-safety, clang, static-analysis

I have a custom thread and lock library written in C (not C++) which I would like to use Clang's thread-safety analysis with.

Everything seems to work OK with C, except for a pseudo-RAII helper I have that mimic's C++'s std::lock_guard.  It looks something like this,

```c
static inline mutex_t* _mutex_autolock_lock(mutex_t* m) {
  mutex_lock(m);
  return m;
}
static inline void _mutex_autolock_unlock(mutex_t** m) {
  mutex_unlock(*m);
}
#define MUTEX_AUTO_LOCK(name, lock) \
  mutex_t* name __attribute__((cleanup(_mutex_autolock_unlock))) = \
    _mutex_autolock_lock(lock); \
  (void)name;
```

then code can use it like so,

```c
{
  MUTEX_AUTO_LOCK(scoped_lock, &mu);
  foo();
  // scoped_lock goes out of scope and automatically unlocks mu
}
```

I can't make this work with Clang's `SCOPED_CAPABILITY` because that (AFAICT) requires a constructor, which I don't have in C.  Is there any way to model this/annotate it such that Clang can use it for thread-safety analysis?

Comment: I haven't found an answer to this, but unfortunately I've found several bigger gaps that make the thread safety analysis far less useful for C code.  #1: struct fields can't be annotated like class members can in C++ (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20403).  #2: in C++, method calls are implicitly considered accesses to the object --- there's no way to replicate this with function calls, so e.g. a linked_list_push(linked_list* list) function call would never be considered an access on the passed list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answers your question, but you might want to have a look at this: [Thread Safety Analysis (TSA) for C](https://github.com/jhi/clang-thread-safety-analysis-for-c)