# Does Clang's Thread Safety Analysis work for C programs using pthread mutexes?

Tags: c, clang, thread-safety, static-analysis

The Clang's [Thread Safety Analysis](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html) is a system of manually applied annotations that can be then checked by the compiler if I specify `-Wthread-safety`.

As far as I can tell, this is C++ only and does not work for C programs. At least I could not make it work.

```c
#include "mutex_annotations.h"
#include <pthread.h>

struct counter {
    pthread_mutex_t mu;
    int count GUARDED_BY(mu);
};
```

```
% clang -std=c11 -c try.c -Wthread-safety
try.c:6:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mu'
```

Comment: There's a LLVM bug for this, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/20777. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543298/using-clang-thread-safety-analysis-with-c11-and-attribute-cleanup

Comment: Also, here's a Linux kernel hacker saying this does not work for C structs, https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2021/10/how-simple-linux-kernel-memory.html